# Going to need some advice: I want to add and display objects in an ArrayList using jTable, then add these records to SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, jtable

Hello there fellow developers,

I have a small issue here that I think I know how to solve, but I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it.
I have a database with a couple of tables, though we are only concerned about 2 tables in here. One table is "Candidate" table and the other one is "Exams" table. Now, whenever I want to add a Candidate to the database, I need to fill his details. The Exams table is linked to that and every candidate has taken different exams at different times. However the record is created in both databases whenever I click "Save" button, but since the Exams table is in every candidate profile, whenever the user adds an exam entry for a particular student, it is not displayed.

Now my solution is to add whatever exam records into an ArrayList and then show the results in jTable, and after "Save" is clicked, all of these records will be added to the database. I don't know if this is the perfect way to do this, but I am open to suggestions of how else can I do it. Note that for exams table I MUST have the Candidate_id, which will not exist if a record is not created by pressing "Save". So in that case, I would create the student record and then add all of his examinations from the ArrayList to the database (as I have now a Candidate_id, which is my foreign key).

Ok here is this "Save" button functionality:

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    mrdb.addCandidatesRecord ("Candidates",txtFName.getText(), 
    txtMName.getText(),
    txtLName.getText(),Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText(),10), 
    Integer.parseInt(txtGrade.getText(), 10));
    mrdb.addExamRecord("Exams", txtExam.getText(), 
    Integer.parseInt(ExamNumber.getText(),10), txtDateTime.getText());
}
```

Anyway, you can see I have an object of "mrdb" which is a class that I made to manage everything that has to do with MySQL database, but my problem here is not the database, it's the "front end". So here is the confusing bit for me. How do I use just an ArrayList and to show records in jTable? So i have started writing this code, and that's in my GUI class just below of the code block I showed above.

```
private class examinations{
    private int id;
    private int candidate_id;
    private String date;
    private String exam;
    private String examNumber;

    public examinations(int id, int student_id, String date, String exam, String examNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.student_id = student_id;
        this.date = date;
        this.exam= exam;
        this.examNumber= examNumber;
    }

    public ArrayList ListExams(){
        ArrayList<exams> list = new ArrayList<exams>();
    
        return list;
    }

    public void addRollToTable(){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tableExams.getModel();
        ArrayList<exams> list = ListExams();
        Object rowData[] = new Object[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            rowData[0] = list.get(i).id;
            rowData[1] = list.get(i).student_id;
            rowData[2] = list.get(i).date;
            rowData[3] = list.get(i).exam;
            rowData[4] = list.get(i).examNumber;

            model.addRow(rowData);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately as you can see, the array here isn't really dynamic. It's array of objects, but I can only put limited amount (so I am gonna have to assume that for each candidate, the school should be able to add an x number of exams (i.e. ALL of the exams), and deal with the overhead. **Is there another way to do this more dynamically?**
And I guess, once those are added, then all I have to do is pull all of those objects out of the array, and use PreparedStatement and add them in the database once the "Save" button is clicked, Correct? Here is the method that I was calling earlier with my mrdb object.

```
public void addExamRecord(String tableName,String exam,
    String examNumber, String date){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(candidate_id, date,"+
                "exam, number_Exam) "+
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
    try{ 
        prepSTMT= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prepSTMT.setInt(1, getCandidate_id()); // create the candidate record, in order to get the candidate_id
        prepSTMT.setString(2, exam);
        prepSTMT.setString(3, examNumber);
        prepSTMT.setDate(4, java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
        prepSTMT.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }   
}
```

If you have any questions for more code, just say, but the problem here is again, most of all, how do I create the illusion of the user adding things to the database, but the records being added by only them clicking one button "Save"?

Comment: Is the issue saving the data or providing a better user experience? Your solution to saving the data is correct as far as I can see - in your button action listener, you need to loop over the data in the table and add each row to the database.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector--

Comment: It's providing better user experience. Because think about it, if you are going to add an exam in the table for that one candidate, and the moment you add the record, it's not there immediately (because you have to SAVE it in order for that record to be there the next time you look at this candidate's profile). I want the record to be seen in there my the user (however it is only saved temporary in an ArrayList). Once the user is ready with whatever candidate they are registering for an exam, they click "Save" and the data saved in the ArrayList are updated in the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the user experience, the data binding/operations in your tables needs to be seamless and should happen with as little user input as possible. Consider not using the save button but saving the data as soon as the row loses its focus.  To do this you will need a standard [MVC design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) where the table row represents a view record, the cells are the view fields and a model provides a persistence layer or object for the data. In between, the controller manages the connection between the two. The key to making it seamless is the communications between these elements.

Use the Swing events to capture UI changes and provide the communication.  See [How To Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) for examples and ideas.  Using those ideas, you can see how a user change in one table, fired as an event, can be listened for/caught and used to update the data in the second table.  You can also see how to "save" the data in a row back to the database when the row selection changes or the row/table loses focus.

Comment: I have an issue with the code up there, and I want to make sure that my project works before going persistent.The rows do not show in the table (I added an object to the LIST then did a System.out.print and it worked). The list is returned and it prints the objects when I test it in the FOR loop in addRolltoTable(), so i am guessing there is some problem in that method.Perhaps I am missing something.